# New to malware analysis, looking for a string type list

Tags: malware

as the title suggests, I'm new to malware analysis and as I was looking over strings in a sample, I came across one that I haven't seen before using + and / (`6AAAAABZg+kFjYm2BgAAUegBAAAAw1WL7IPk+`etc...).

I am wondering if there is a list of some kind out there that has examples of certain types of string, like `SGVsbG8=` is base64, `48 65 6c 6c 6f` is hexadecimal, and so on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `+` and `/` you can tell this **is** Base64 per [RFC 4648, 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-4):

- Characters `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/`
- Padding `=`, `==` or nothing in the end.

Then there is:

- Binary `01`
- Decimal `0123456789`
- Base16 a.k.a. hexadecimal: `0123456789ABCDEF` (case insensitive) [RFC 4648, 8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-8)
- Base32:

  - [RFC 4648, 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-6): A-Z, 2-7: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567` (omitting 0 and 1)
  - z-base-32: `ybndrfg8ejkmcpqxot1uwisza234h769`
  - Crockford's Base32: `0123456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTVWXYZ` + possible checksums
  - base32hex, [RFC 4648, 7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-7): `0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV`
  - Geohash: `0123456789bcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz` (omitting a, i, l and o)
  - ...many others, some having completely overlapping sets in different order
- Base36: 0-9, A-Z: `0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`
- Base58 removes `0`, `O`, `I`, `l`, `+` and `/` from Base64, but has variations:

  - `123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz` used by Bitcoin
  - `123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ` used by Flickr
- Base85 or Ascii85. Impossible to format here, as literally having "`" in it. See [RFC 1924, 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1924#section-4.2).
- URL encoding a.k.a. Percent-Encoding from [RFC 3986, 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1)
- Punycode [RFC 3492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3492)
- Endless list of proprietary or undocumented encodings...

As you can already see, **it's only possible to rule out what an arbitrary string can't be** and then make educated guesses on what it *might* be. After that you'd still have to know whether the contents encoded are anything meaningful to your. As it depends entirely on the context, it's not possible to analyse this kind of string on Q/A sites.

Comment: I thought it was base64 given the character set was also an extracted string, but I decoded it and got nothing good out of it. I guess that'll happen though. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I have no such list because it might heavyly depend on the context.
If it belongs to crypto or compression, then the bytes should be pretty random, so no list would be helpful.

But might worth to know:

- [Public-Keys tend to start with similar pattern](https://serverfault.com/questions/526399)
- [Password hash types could be guessed too](http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/john-the-ripper-hash-formats)
- and to [know the mime types and their magic bytes](https://github.com/minad/mimemagic/blob/master/lib/mimemagic/tables.rb#L1641) is useful for me

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Thanks for the links, I'll check them out more in depth soon.